# Firebase Google auth, signing out and logging in again will log in with the last signed account

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Google Auth, signing out and logging in again will log in with the last signed account. How can I make it show the "choose account" dialog?
this is what I did to log out.
          `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`
and then I call sign-in activity.
Also, the logout button is in a different activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this is what I did to log out.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

When you try to sign out using the above line of code, it basically means that you are signing out **only** from Firebase.

> I am using Firebase Google Auth, signing out and logging in again will log in with the last signed account. How can I make it show the "choose account" dialog?

As I see, you are using Google authentication. Signing out from Firebase doesn't mean that you are automatically signed out from Google. It doesn't. To sign out from Google you have to explicitly add a call to [GoogleSignInClient#signOut()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient#signOut()) method, like this:

```
googleSignInClient.signOut();
```

Please don't forget that the sign-out operation is **asynchronous**, meaning that you have to wait until the operation completes, which may take some time. Since this method returns an object of type [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task), you can use [addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener listener)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#addOnCompleteListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CTResult%3E)) method, to know when you are completely signed out.

Comment: It works! But do you know how can i make this code if the button to log out is in a differed activity from form the mGoogleSignInClient.(i ask that because when i make the mGoogleSignInClient static to be able to access it form the other activity, the code doesn't work)

Comment: You should pass that object to the desired activity or create it right over there. Or why not, directly inject it using [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android).